# How to display custom product description page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Good Evening!
I have created a theme for WordPress and then used it as a website. I added WooCommerce plugin for adding products. The cart page, checkout page, account page etc. work fine but when I click on a product to get the detail of the product nothing displays (not even the header & footer). The store URL is 127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/. When I click on a product it goes to 127.0.0.1:81/product/[product-name]/. I created product page template with PHP as

```
 `<?php /* Template Name: productPage */ 
    get_header();
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

When I open the URL 127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/product/ the products are displayed properly but when I click on any product then the new URL which is 127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/product/[product-name] displays nothing.
its empty page with nothing gets loaded. (shown in the picture). I tried using the product page as a parent but that also didn't work. Hope to get some help here.
[image]

Comment: If you correctly installed woocommerce you shouldn't have any issue with the product detail page. Test that with "Storefront" theme which is the default made by the woocommerce guys, if it works with that theme, you have broken something with yours

Comment: Thats fine but I am limited to only this theme otherwise I would have done it with some other theme.